# class/interface design approach for given scenario

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, class-design

I have 10-15 different types of results to calculate say AResult, BResult etc. All result calculation return single type of value(consider an `integer` value).
To calculate these I needs input parameters which are mostly common but a few needs different ones as follows:

```
Input parameters example:
    AResult needs  int x, int y, int a[], int b[]
    BResult needs  int x, int y, int a[], boolean c
    CResult needs  int x, int y, int a[], boolean c, boolean d
    DResult needs  int x, int y, int p[], boolean e
    .....
```

**NOTE** that in some cases result of one calculation is also used in other result calculations, but that is only in few cases and not all.

The way I am doing it is through *Approach1* as follows:

**Approach 1:**

I am defining an interface which has single method to calculate result taking an `InputParameter obj`. In the implementation classes I would extract out the values from `InputParameter obj` whichever are applicable to that particular type of result. Here is the snippet of my sample code:

```
public interface Result {
    int calculate(InputParameter obj);
}

public class AResult implements Result {
    public int calculate(InputParameter obj){
      // code
     }

}

public class BResult implements Result {
    public int calculate(InputParameter obj)){
      // code
     }


}

public class InputParameter {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int a[];
    int b[];
    int p[];
    boolean c;
    boolean d;
    boolean e;
    ....
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

As an example, say I create an `InputParameter` object and set values of all the fields in there. I pass this object to aResultObject.calculate(InputParameter obj) , dResultObject.calculate(InputParameter obj) and so on.

`AResult` needs  `int x, int y, int a[], int b[]`   which I extract from `InputParameter obj` do the calulations and return result.

`DResult` needs  `int x, int y, int p[], boolean e`   which I extract from same `InputParameter obj` to do the calulations and return result.

**Note** that I might have to do other sets of result calculations, so may create multiple objects of `InputParameter`, `AResult`, `BResult` so on. Just want to convey that `InputParameter` need not be singleton.

---

**Approach2:**

Having `calculate()` method without any parameter and setting these values in individual Result class constructors.

As @Duncan pointed out one drawback of *Approach1* is that, here I might miss setting the required fields in `InputParameter` object for a given result calculation. And when I actually try to extract out the value from `InputParameter` object in `calculation(InputParameter obj)` method, I discover it is not set.

```
public interface Result {
   int calculate();
}

public class AResult implements Result {
   public AResult(int x, int y, int a[], int b[]) {
      //set input params
   }
   public int calculate() {
      //calculate and return AResult
   }
}
```

---

**Approach3:**

Create Single class (or may be just 2-3 classes) for Result and then just have separate methods to calculate different results.

I am also considering this approach because in some cases result of one calculation is also used in other result calculations (but that is only in few cases and not all).

```
public class Result {
   // various fields...

   int calculateResultA(){...}
   int calculateResultB(){...}
   int calculateResultC(){...}
}
```

Is the above mentioned **Approach1** good for given situaltion? or the other alternatives are better?

Comment: I now wonder if my answer has confused matters. Is the input data always the same, but different "result producers" do different things with the input data? If so, perhaps your original design is quite reasonable.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the input data to calculate `AResult` may have few things in common with other results (say `BResult`) but may need few extra input parameters than `BResult`. Same applies to all kinds of results that I want to calculate. So essentially the inputs required to calculates different results are not all same. Is it clear now, or shall I give some exmple to clarify it further?

Comment: The values of your "int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int a[];
    int b[];
    boolean c;
    boolean d;" remain the same for all calculations?

Comment: Yes, they are same. But as I said some calculations need x, y and b while other need x, y, a, c and d. So on ....

Comment: @Learner - In that case your original design is correct.. I think even Duncan agrees (read his first comment).

Comment: @Learner: could you please describe your use case? I still think there might be some misunderstanding... What each of you mean by "the data are the same" in the comments? Do you mean there is a SINGLE instance of the POJO class InputParameter (which can be make singleton) for all the calculation, or by "the same" you just mean the business interpretation? Please talk more about your real use case.

Comment: I updated the question to describe my use case, please take a look.

Comment: @Learner I still don't fully understand what you are doing, so it's hard to advise on the correct approach. Is it possible you can explain what you are really doing, rather than talking in an abstract sense?

Comment: @Duncan, I added more detailed explaination of my problem.

Comment: Do you have a real example of code that manipulates `Result` objects ? Is there a particular reason why you need to abstract out the notions of `Result` (which is more of a `Calculation` IMO) and `InputParameter` ?

Comment: @Duncan, guillaume31 : Sorry but due to confidentiality reasons, I am not allowed to write real names here. However except the real names I have kind of tried to describe it completely. Please let me know if something is still not clear and I will try to explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest approach 2 with a factory.
The pattern is (maybe) ***command***.

### Factory approach

```
package blammy.result;

public interface Result
{
    int calculate();
}

package blammy.result.impl;

public class AResult
implements Result;
{
    /*
     * Protected constructor to hinder naughty construction.
    */
    protected AResult(
        int x,
        int y,
        int a[],
        int b[])
    {
        ... blah;
    }

    public int calculate()
    {
        int returnValue;
        returnValue = ... blah.
        return returnValue;
    }
}
public class BResult
implements Result;
{
    /*
     * Protected constructor to hinder naughty construction.
    */
    protected BResult(
        int x,
        int y,
        boolean c)
    {
        ... blah;
    }

    public int calculate()
    {
        int returnValue;
        returnValue = ... blah.
        return returnValue;
    }
}

public static class ResultFactory
{
    public static Result createResult(
        int x,
        int y,
        int a[],
        int b[])
    {
        return new AResult(x, y, a, b);
    }

    public static Result createResult(
        int x,
        int y,
        boolean c)
    {
        return new BResult(x, y, c);
    )
}
```

### Edit 1

If different calculations require the same parameters, then you should use descriptive name in the factory and in the class name.  For example:

```
public static class ResultFactory

    public static Result createBlammy(
        int x,
        int y,
        int a[],
        int b[])
    {
        return new ResultBlammy(x, y, a, b);
    }

    public static Result createHooty(
        int x,
        int y,
        int a[],
        int b[])
    {
        return new ResultHooty(x, y, a, b);
    }
```

Comment: Actually I can not rely on number of parameters or their order to decide which result to calculate. So how about having different factory method names like `createAResult`, `createBResult` etc. Is that also fine ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, use constructor and define the interface `Result` to have a method `public int calculate()` which take no parameter.
**DISCLAIMER** from this point on, are personal interpretations of a couple of good principles. Evaluate them, criticize them if you do not agree and do not take them for given facts (the principles are really good, the interpretation in your case may be not that good). 
I will try to avoid using objects having low cohesion, where cohesion is defined in the book `Growing object oriented software guided by tests` as

> An element’s cohesion is a measure of whether its responsibilities form a meaningful unit. For example, a class that parses both dates and URLs is not coherent, because they’re unrelated concepts. Think of a machine that washes both clothes and dishes—it’s unlikely to do both well.2 At the other extreme, a class that parses only the punctuation in a URL is unlikely to be coherent, because it doesn’t represent a whole concept. To get anything done, the programmer will have to find other parsers for protocol, host, resource, and so on. Features with “high” coherence are easier to maintain.

In your case, I believe `InputParameter` has the responsibility to hold parameter for different classes, so in my opinion its responsibility is not a meaningful unit (and even if it is basically a value object, by some extension it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByOwmqah_nuGNHEtcU5OekdDMkk/edit?pli=1))

Comment: I added more detailed explaination of my problem.

Comment: I am definitely against your third approach. If you want to add a new `calculate` method you have to add a new method to `Result`, thus you are violating the [Open-Closed Principle](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgN2M5MTkwM2EtNWFkZC00ZTI3LWFjZTUtNTFhZGZiYmUzODc1/edit?hl=en). As I said, and per the reasons (maybe not exhaustive) I pointed out in my answer, I would go for your `approach 2`.

Comment: I was thinking of `Approach3` because I though why to create 10-15 classes unneccesarily as my results calculation almost need same set of inputs and hence can be put into same class with methods calculating these results.

Comment: Well, `Approach3` is the one I dislike more. Try to read these  [Principles of Object Oriented Design](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) to get a full insight of my motivations.